# Счетчик из string C++

Tags: c++, строки

Необходимо реализовать счетчик из числа, записанного в String. Т.е. при каждой итерации цикла стринговое число надо увеличить на 1. Т.е. было "123", после следующей итерации должно стать "124" и т.д.

У меня проблема с разрядами.
Вот такой кусок кода у меня увеличивает только от 0 до 9, а как сделать увеличение и добавление нового разряда (десятки, сотни и .т.д) - не знаю.

```
if(str[(str.size()-1]-'0'< 9)
   str[(str.size()-1]+=1;
```

Comment: А не проще увеличивать число, а в в строку его писать через sprintf()?

Comment: Может проще каждый раз преобразовывать его в int, увеличивать и записывать результат обратно?

Comment: Если разряд равен 9 - то делаете его 0 и при этом ставите какую то переменную в 1. на следующем цикле, когда обрабатываете старший разряд прибавляете к нему 1+эта переменная. Если переноса не возникает - то переменную обнуляете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, от человека хотят именно работу со строкой...
Тогда - вот:

```
void inc(string&s)
{
    int l = s.length();
    bool carry = true;
    for(int i = l-1; carry && i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (carry) s[i]++;
        if (carry = (s[i] > '9')) s[i] = '0';
    }
    if (carry) s = '1' + s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "193";
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        inc(s);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    s = "993";
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        inc(s);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно это сделать следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string cnt( "999" );

    std::cout << cnt << std::endl;

    cnt = std::to_string( std::stoul( cnt ) + 1 );

    std::cout << cnt << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
999
1000
```

Comment: Только вот если cnt окажется больше, чем 2^64, то ничего хорошего их этого не выйдет.

Comment: @MikalaiRamanovich  Как сказал один киногерой в фильме с участием Шварцнеггера, я люблю умных людей, но не люблю умников.  Обычно счетчики предполагают использование некоторых целочисленных объектов для использования их в качестве счетчика. Так что если вас не устраивает, допустим, тип usigned long, то вы можете использовать тип unsigned long long. Но это все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: @MikalaiRamanovich Предложенное мною решение совершенное корректное. Если у вас возникают такие счетчики, которые не умещаются ни в один целочисленный тип, то вам придется выбрать другое решение. Но это совершенно не означает, что мое решение некорректное.